# Write the value of a field as a css class to another field

Tags: entities

Could someone point me in the right direction to write the value of a field A to the css classes array of field B?

In my case I'm using a field collection (with text and file/image field, to make a sort of paragraph) and want to make a select field (with 4 preset options) so the node creator can choose if they want the file/image field displayed top, left, or right.

I don't really want to mess around with dynamic views or special formatters, just write the value of my select list to the class of the file/image field wrapper.

Comment: You can do it with JQuery. Just find out the class of the field you want to align and through Jquery define conditional css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample code to help you further which adds a class on a field (`field_image`) based on the value of another field (List field of type `text`) (`field_alignment`).

You will need to implement 2 preprocess hooks:

1. On node `preprocess` to retrieve the objects / values of the fields and add extra datamember which contains the class value
2. On field `preprocess` to retrieve the previously added extra datamember and merge it with the default `classes_array` part of a field

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) 
{
    if (!isset($variables['field_image']) || !isset($variables['field_alignment'])) {
        return false; // if 1 of both fields is not available, don't do anything
    }

    $alignment = reset($variables['field_alignment']); // retrieve first item of array
    $variables['content']['field_image']['#extra_classes'] = array($alignment['value']); // add an extra datamember containing an array with the value of the other field
}

function YOURTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables)
{
    $field = $variables['element'];
    if ($field['#field_name'] !== 'field_image') {
        return false; // only manipulate the image field
    }

    if (!isset($field['#extra_classes'])) {
        return false; // don't do anything if the array with extra classes is not available
    }

    $variables['classes_array'] = array_merge(
        $variables['classes_array'], $field['#extra_classes']); // merge the default field classes with the new added class
}
```

**Update - When assigning class to field_image which sits within a field collection (named field_collection)**

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) 
{
    if (!isset($variables['field_collection']) || !isset($variables['field_classes'])) {
        return false; 
    }

    if (!isset($variables['content']['field_collection'])) {
        return false;
    }

    $alignment = reset($variables['field_classes']);
    foreach (element_children($variables['content']['field_collection']) as $index) {
         foreach ($variables['content']['field_collection'][$index]['entity']['field_collection_item'] as &$field_collection_item) {
              if (!isset($field_collection_item['field_image'])) {
                  continue;
              } 

              $field_collection_item['field_image']['#extra_classes'] = array($alignment['value']);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: THank you!! This works, but not on fields inside my 'field collection'. Do you know anything about that by chance?

Comment: I've updated the coded with an example when working with a field collection.

Comment: THank you again! wonderful! :) Got it all working up to the point of setting the #extra_classes and somehow though i can't seem to get the classes_array merger to happen in the preprocess_field... Also, (i guess this is more a php question), i have more than 1 field collection, so ['field_collection'][0] doesnt work. :/ Have to loop or something huh?

Comment: Are you using a reference in the `foreach` loop when assigning the `#extra_classes` array value by using the `&$field_collection_item` syntax (with the `&` in front?

Comment: I've update the code when having multiple items in a field collection.

Comment: Thanks once again! I came to something similar, but yours is more clean. I've moved the 'field_classes' though because that is also inside the collection, and had to adjust to find the value for it. http://pastebin.com/XZ9zFLMe  Getting an error sometimes though... `Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in element_children()`

Comment: To remove the error, you need to add extra condition just before the loop using the same `isset` logic. In your case it would be `if (!isset($variables['content']['field_paragraph'])) { return false; }`  (http://pastebin.com/mLJcPKHs)

Comment: ok thanks! seems kind of redundant. Seems like its checking twice. `$variables['field_paragraph']` then `$variables['content']['field_paragraph']`. But thats makes it work, I'm super happy! Thank you much!